# Tools to identify Class or Div for Scrapping

Tags: web-scraping

To build my scrapping script and identify the labels of divs, classes and trees on a website, I use Chrome's development tools and inspection tools in particular.

In some cases this can quickly become difficult to read or analyse.

Do you know of any tools that can provide a user experience to do this ?

Thank you.